# detect usb insertion and set bit

Tags: encryption, usb, detect, insertion

I want to detect the insertion of a usb thumbdrive and have the insertion set a flag on the thumbdrive in order that the individual receiving the thumbdrive through the mail will be able to determine if the device has been accessed between the time the device was posted in the mail and its arrival at the intended destination.

I am sending pad files and want to be sure the files have not been examined/copied.

Perhaps I'm headed in the wrong direction. Should I instead check access time on the files. However, it seems to me that is rather easily jiggered.

In the past, I have wrapped the drive in crushed foil and inscribed a barely visible mark on the foil which the receiver is directed to discern before unwrapping. Works fairly well. But there must be a better way to do this.

Any the smallest help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not actually encrypt the data on it and give the key in some out-of-band way to the receiver? It's not like you can anything about your data being read midway, so this way you can be sure that only the intended recipient can read it.

Comment: Should work, I would recommend to use PGP / GPG for something like this, sharing public keys first.